# PHP - Get Number of Pages

Tags: php, pagination, page-numbering

How do I get the number of pages if I know the total number of items there are and how many items are shown on each page? For example, I know that I have 11 items and each page shows 10 items. So I would have 2 pages. How would I get the number of pages in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: Like... how to do the math (hint: `total / per-page` rounded up)? Or do you have a problem specific to PHP?

Answer (score 18):

Try [ceil()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function.

```
$pages = ceil( $items / $itemsPerPage );
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe the ceiling function is what you're looking for.

```
ceil($items/$items_per_page)
```

Comment: Number of pages should be integer. I suggest to wrap with intval() call:  `intval( ceil( $items / $items_per_page ) );`

Answer (score 3):

```
$count_pages = ceil($total / $items_per_page);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick for you. Ceil rounds numbers upwards, always up.

```
<?php
$maxNrOfPages = ceil($max/$itemsPerPage);
?>
```